# Not able to mount drive formatted as NTFS in Windows 10 on LinuxMint

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, mount, ntfs

I installed Linux mint alogside windows 10. I was able to mount drives formatted in windows 10. However now I am not able to mount these drives.

It generates the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/legend/New Volume: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda3" "/media/legend/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Windows, search for `CMD`
2. Right-click on it, then left-click on Run as administrator
3. Confirm UAC's prompt
4. Type and confirm:

   ```
   chkdsk c: /f
   ```

   or other partitions too.
5. The system's partition can be repaired only in boot mode; so it will ask you whether you wish run run Check Disk at boot. Type <kbd>Y</kbd> and confirm.
6. Restart. Errors will be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the **hibernation** and the **fast startup** on windows

`man ntfs-3g`:

```
Windows hibernation and fast restarting
   On computers which can be dual-booted into Windows or Linux, Windows has to be fully shut down before booting into Linux, otherwise the NTFS file systems on internal disks
   may be left in an inconsistent state and changes made by Linux may be ignored by Windows.

   So, Windows may not be left in hibernation when starting Linux, in order to avoid inconsistencies. Moreover, the fast restart feature available on recent  Windows  systems
   has to be disabled. This can be achieved by issuing as an Administrator the Windows command which disables both hibernation and fast restarting :

      powercfg /h off
```

From the **Shutdown settings**  un-check the **Turn on fast startup**